# Transpose long to wide in SAS

Tags: sas, subset, large-data

I have a very large data set (18 million observations) that I would like to transpose by subsetting based on one variable and creating 900 new variables out of those sub/ets. Example code and desired output format below:
Example data:

```
data long1 ; 
  input famid year faminc ; 
cards ; 
var1 96 40000 
var1 97 40500 
var1 98 41000 
var2 96 45000 
var2 97 45400 
var2 98 45800 
var3 96 75000 
var3 97 76000 
var3 98 77000 
; 
run;
```

Code:

```
proc transpose data = data; by famid; var faminc; run;
```

**Desired output format:**
[image]

Because of the size of my data set, I'm wondering if I have use a do loop to find first and last observations of each var and then iteratively subset. Does anyone know a sql or proc to achieve the desired output format?

Comment: Is your question how to make the `proc transpose` work or how to do something more efficiently than sorting and proc transposing?

Comment: I will comment that going to a wide format may not help, almost always further processing is easier in a long format.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your subsetting would be based on, but if it's only the *id*, it is rather straightforward.

Using the example from [this ucla's page on proc sort](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/ltow_transpose.htm), your example would work fine using slightly modified input data:

```
data long; 
  input id year faminc ; 
  datalines ; 
1 96 40000 
1 97 40500 
1 98 41000 
2 96 45000 
2 97 45400 
2 98 45800 
3 96 75000 
3 97 76000 
3 98 77000 
; 

proc sort data=long;
  by year;
run;

proc transpose data=long out=wide(drop=_name_) prefix=var; 
  by year; 
  var faminc; 
run;
```

### Results

```
year var1  var2  var3 
96   40000 45000 75000 
97   40500 45400 76000 
98   41000 45800 77000
```

---

**UCLA's SAS help pages** are much clearer than SAS's own as regards to using `proc transpose` in both directions. Here are 4 valuable links...

[Long to Wide with Proc Transpose](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/ltow_transpose.htm)
[Wide to Long with Proc Transpose](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/wtol_transpose.htm)

[Long to Wide with Data Step](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/longtowide_data.htm)
[Wide to Long with Data Step](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/widetolong_data.htm)

Comment: I hadn't realized that the OP hadn't succcessfully implemented a `transpose` step. Thanks for pointing this out, it's fundamental to know how to `proc transpose`.

Answer (score 1):

Transpose steps like this are easily done with the `array` statement. Example for your code would be something like:

```
data new (keep = year var1-var3);
  set data;
  by year;
  array vars {3} var1-var3;
  retain var1-var3;
  if first.year then i=1;
  else i+1;
  vars{i} = faminc;
  if last.year then output;
run;
```

But I don't have SAS to double check this. Also see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiut5XE75TNAhVJ-mMKHThQCC0QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ats.ucla.edu%2Fstat%2Fsas%2Flibrary%2Fnesug98%2Fp156.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEH9GyJ7RQLAWreO6aLiuKqRh3Wcg&sig2=abB48pIrqDLLhy7ZYMtr9g&cad=rja).

There are no good transpose procedures in PROC SQL.Too limited.

Comment: Thank you for your response, very helpful. My variable names are actually character strings without consistent naming convention, so they aren't var1-... as I wrote in my code. Will the array technique work with this type of data?

Comment: Yes, all that is required is to list the variables in the array statement. If you have a variable in your dataset that contains the new variable name, proc transpose has the `IDLABEL` and `ID` statements to create the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Here are links to well tested in battle macros from the book "Data Preparation for Analytics"

From the sas community wiki you can download macro definitions.

Goto http://support.sas.com/kb/32/121.html for transposing from WIDE to LONG and http://support.sas.com/kb/32/122.html for transposing from LONG to WIDE.

More Details on "Data Preparation for Analytics" can be found under http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Data_Preparation_for_Analytics, where you can download all macros, programs and datasets for the book.

Hope this help