# (SAS) How to pick up dates with ID-based data?

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and trying to program a simple code.

Original data:

```
TableA
ID   |Date      |Type
1     20111111    A
2     20081014    C
3     20051126    A
...
100   20160421    B
```

From this original data, I want to pick up dates by Type.

Like following

```
Result (only picking up A and B)
ID   | DateofA  | DateofB
1    | 20111111 |    
2    |          |    
3    | 20051126 |
...
100  |          | 20160421
```

Could anyone do this?

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose long to wide in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670230/transpose-long-to-wide-in-sas)

Comment: I can guess what's wrong but you need to show the code you used and a few of the data lines exactly is in the file you are reading from.

Comment: Its not clear what the logic is here at all. Is it just a flip? Why is the second ID missing the value?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to achieve this using Proc Transpose. To pick up the dates, you need to sort the dataset by Id. and then transpose the dataset by Id(keeping it fixed). The Id statement is also used to create columns using Type. Following is the approach I used:

```
data inp;
input Id 3. Date yymmdd8. type $2.;
type=strip(type);
format date date9.;
datalines;
1  20111111 A
2  20081014 C
3  20051126 A
4  20031212 B
5  20041127 C
6  20010904 A
7  20010803 C
8  20000702 B
9  19990601 A
10 19980701 C
;
run;

proc sort data=inp; by Id; run;

proc transpose data=inp
               out=outp 
               NAME=Transposed_Col
               prefix=DATEOf;
            by Id;
            id type;
run;
```